# Java: Process statements which are within an overridden method

Tags: java, class, methods, overriding

So I have my base Class X, and Class Y which extends it.
I have a number of methods in class X which are all overridden in class Y,
I would like to put a few statements in one of these methods which get called even when the method is overridden, without having to put any extra code into Class Y.

Is there any way to do this?

```
public class X
 {
     protected void method()
         {
             // vital statements;
         }
 }

public class Y extends X
 {
     protected void method()
             {
             /* vital statements still need to happen
             * would rather not have to call it
             * in every single class that extends X
             */
             // non vital statement;
         }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common -- and essentially only -- way to do this is using the `super` keyword:

```
     protected void method()
     {
         super.method();
         non vital statement;
     }
```

I say "essentially only" because there are other ways to do this, but they require more change. One technique is to make the central method final and public (so it can be called but not overridden), and have it call a protected abstract method (which can be overridden but not called). Then folks can customize the behavior of a subclass by overriding just the abstract method. This is called the *template method pattern.*

A third way to accomplish what you want is by using [*aspects*.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) Using aspect-oriented programming, your "vital statements" could be added to the subclass methods at runtime or compile time, using some behind-the-scenes bytecode magic. This requires some special tooling and adds some complexity to your build system, but it has the advantage of being completely invisible to the authors of the subclasses.

Comment: still requires code in every single method in every single class which extends X... but it is my fall back

Comment: "essentially only way to do this" is correct.  There isn't really an alternative.

Answer (score 4):

You need a template method http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern

Vital statement would be called in a template method

```
public class X {
  final void template() {
    Vital statement;
    method();
  }

  void method() {
    // do something;
  }
}

public class Y extends X {
  @Override
  void method() {
    // specific code to the class Y
  }
}
```

Comment: so whenever I call method() in Y, it still does the "// do something" part?

Comment: instead of calling the `method` from `Y` you should be calling its `template` method (inherited from `X`)

Answer (score 1):

No, this is impossible. You'll have to find a different way to achieve what you want, perhaps via a [template method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).